# php fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given

Tags: php

I have code like this:

```
$filename = "history-login ".date("d M Y").".txt";
$docroot = "public/file/".$filename;
$txt  = "username : ".$admin_session->username."\n";
$txt .= "time : ".date("d M Y , h:i:s")."\n";

if (file_exists($docroot)){
        $myfile = file_put_contents($docroot, $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND)  or die("Unable to write!");
}else{
    $myfile = fopen($docroot, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");                      
}

fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

and i received a message warning like this:

> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given

Can you help me figure out how to fix this?

Comment: I can answer your question but can you add some comments where everything is so it will be easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that when the file exists, the `$myfile = file_put_contents()` fragment is being executed, but as documentation says - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php - `file_put_contents()` returns int, not a resource, which is expected by `fwrite()` and `fclose()`. So just put these 2 functions into the `else` branch, like this one:

```
if (file_exists($docroot)){
        $myfile = file_put_contents($docroot, $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND)  or die("Unable to write!");
}else{
    $myfile = fopen($docroot, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");                      
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code jump into the case $docroot exist, so the $myfile doesn't a file resource object.
I think you just need to return after file_put_contents

```
if (file_exists($docroot)){
        $myfile = file_put_contents($docroot, $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND)  or die("Unable to write!");
return;
}else{
    $myfile = fopen($docroot, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");                      
}
```

Comment: I tried to use that to but it's still not working.